# SSH "Too many authentication failures" when trying to connect from Ubuntu to Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

When I try to ssh from my Ubuntu Desktop to Raspberry pi, It throws the error "Too many authentication failures" and dies, and does not prompt me for the password

Answer (score 10):

After enabling the `-v` verbose option I found that my SSH client is trying out all available ssh keys stored locally to try and connect to the raspberry pi and then gives up.

Since I want an interactive login (be able to enter the pi/raspberry password manually) when trying to SSH to my raspberry pi, I had to add the following entry to ~/.ssh/ssh_config

```
Host 192.168.1.10
           PreferredAuthentications=password
```

Note: 
1) IP address mentioned above is that of my Raspberry Pi.
2) If you are using an SSH key to login (which you should ideally), you wont need this.

Comment: Quick solution: `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password <hostname_or_ip>`, which sets the option for that single connection. Once connected you can add your key as appropriate, and SSH should work fine after that.